# Python script for balancing till not working

Tags: python

Comes up with crazy value.... Trying to make an easy way to balance tills at work just by entering in the amount of bills, coins.

Anyone have any insight on what is wrong?

```
#End of day till count simplified
myfile = open('Endofdaycount.txt', 'w')
hundreds = 100
fiftes = 50
twenties = 20
tens = 10
fives = 5
ones = 1
quarters = .25
dimes = .10
nickels = .05
pennies = .01
rollofquarters = 10
rollofdimes = 5
rollofnickels = 2
rollofpennies = .50

prompt1 = input ("How many hundreds are in the till?") + str(hundreds)
prompt2 = input ("How many fiftes are in the till?") + str(fiftes)
prompt3 = input ("How many twenties are in the till?") + str(twenties)
prompt4 = input ("How many tens are in the till?") + str(tens)
prompt5 = input ("How many fives are in the till?") + str(fives) 
prompt6 = input ("How many ones are in the till?") + str(ones)
prompt7 = input ("How many quarters are in the till?") + str(quarters)
prompt8 = input ("How many dimes are in the till?") + str(dimes)
prompt9 = input ("How many nickels are in the till?") + str(nickels)
prompt10 = input ("How many pennies are in the till?") + str(pennies)
prompt11 = input ("How many rolls of quarters are in the till?") + str(rollofquarters)
prompt12 = input ("How many rolls of dimes are in the till?") + str(rollofdimes)
prompt13 = input ("How many rolls of nickles are in the till?") + str(rollofnickels)
prompt14 = input ("How many rolls of pennies are in the till?") + str(rollofpennies)
total = str(prompt1 + prompt2 + prompt3 + prompt4 + prompt5 + prompt6 + prompt7 + prompt8 + prompt9 + prompt10 +prompt11 +prompt12 +prompt13 +prompt14)
myfile.close()
print (total)
```

Comment: Could you please include a sample of input and the output?

Comment: You are concatenating strings, not adding up numbers. See the duplicate on how to convert inputs to integers.

Comment: i changed to int(input however the output comes out all messed up